# Variable name what is considered to be better design?

Tags: php

I know it may sound silly, because the following example will lead to the same results.

But still I want to know what is considered preferable

**option 1**

```
$input['search']  = 'user_unsafe_string';
$input['search']  = isset($_GET["q"]) ? htmlentities($_GET['q']) : '';

echo $input['search'];
```

**option 2**

```
$input['search']  = 'user_unsafe_string';
$safe_search  = isset($_GET["q"]) ? htmlentities($_GET['q']) : '';

echo $safe_search;
```

Is one of the option is better?

Is there a chance even if it low, that in the first option 
`echo $input['search']` In some situations will lead to output `$input['search']` without `htmlentities`

Comment: If your code is working, and you're looking to improve it, you should ask the question on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Here on Stack Overflow, we help you out with code problems. Asking which approach is better, could be considdered as Primarily Opinion Based and simply lead to closure of your question.

Comment: As for your question, it makes no difference at all. In option 1, you are setting the value in an array. In option 2 you're setting it in a variable. The ternary operator simply evaluates if `$_GET["q"]` is set. If it is, it applies `htmlentities()`, if not it doesn't. Keep in mind that `isset()` only checks if the variable exists. It doesn't check if it's empty. So `http://somelink.com/index.php?q=` will return true, even though it's empty. Use `!empty()` instead of `isset()` to check if it exists and if it's not empty.